# Load names from JSON to Expandable List Android

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

How to load the Name of places from JSON File to Expandable List?My json file is stored on the assets folder. Im new to android.Please help me,thanks. heres the link to my code below:

http://textuploader.com/kv72

Comment: FIY, you can post your code here my friend, you don't need to provide a link to it. Gonna edit this time for you

Comment: i cant post the code .it says too much code.

Comment: It says there is too much code and not much explanation, that's why!

Comment: Anyway, why would you need an expandable list and not a common listview? It would be good if you could post your json as well

Comment: I need a expandable list because the places are categorized into 4 .heres my json file`{
   "Dine":[
      {
         "name":"Place name",
         "address":"Address Here",
         "lat":15.475245,
         "lng":120.593438,
         "category":""
      } ] }`

Comment: Try this: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: yes.thats exactly i did. the problem is i want to parse the names from a json file. not as hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your "prepareListData()" method. You need to work on it, you are missing few steps & did some wrong steps. Follow below links :

1] [How to set data to Expandable List View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917436/how-to-set-data-to-expandable-list-view)

2] [how to make ExpandableListView with JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269261/how-to-make-expandablelistview-with-json-array)

I hope, these will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a json parser like for instance Jackson where you can do annotations in java objects. In that way you can define the structure of your classes in the same maner as the json structure and insert the objects you create into the list. For example an Json object called User:

```
public class User {

   @JsonProperty("username")
   public String mUsername;

   @JsonProperty("email")
   public String mEmail;
}
```

You can even define other classes so that you can parse all of your json like for instance:

```
public class SomeData {

   @JsonProperty("id")
   public String mId;

   @JsonProperty("users")
   public List<User> mUsers;
}
```

In this example the json will have a list of User objects and the parser inserts them into the variable mUsers.

Link to jackson github: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations